# What's the difference between Module.fun and fun?

Tags: ruby

```
module MyMod
  def fun1
  #...
  end 

  def MyMod.fun2
  #...
  end
end
```

What's the difference between fun1 and MyMod.fun2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fun1` is an instance method. Which can be accessible only when any class included that module inside its definition.

```
p RUBY_VERSION

module MyMod

  def fun1
  p "hi"
  end 

  def MyMod.fun2
  p "hello"
  end
end

class Foo
include MyMod
end
Foo.new.fun1
MyMod.fun2
p MyMod.instance_methods(false)
p MyMod.public_class_method("fun2")
```

*Output:*

```
"2.0.0"
"hi"
"hello"
[:fun1]
MyMod
```